# Declare type where type of one field based on value of another field

Tags: typescript, types

I want to declare the type like this:

```
type ElementCreatorParameters = {
  tagName: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[tagName]): void
}
```

The first problem is that I can't use the value of field `tagName` to define the type of `element` (if I'm correct it is because of the types must be static)

The second problem is that when I start to using the generic types I need to pass this generic type into `children` field:

```
type ElementCreatorParameters<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> = {
  tagName: T
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters<T>>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]): void
}
```

but the `children` are not the same generic type as their parent

I want all of this to be able to define object like this:

```
{
  tagName: 'form',
  onCreate: (element) => {
    // Here the element must be HTMLFormElement 
    element
  },
  children: [
    {
      tagName: 'input',
      onCreate: (element) => {
        // Here the element must be HTMLInputElement
        element
      },
      children: [
        {
          tagName: 'a',
          onCreate: (element) => {
            // Here the element must be HTMLAnchorElement
            element
          },
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgvP6W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes! This is what I wanted. Please post an answer and I will accept it. If I'm right, you have recursively created all possible variants of type `ElementCreatorParameters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent `ElementCreatorParameters` as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where each member in the union corresponds to one choice of `tagName` from `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`.  Sure, there would be more than 100 members in that union, so it would be annoying to write that out manually... but it's a finite number so a union is at least a possible solution.  And luckily we don't have to write out the union members individually; we can get the compiler to evaluate it for us.  Like this:

```
type ElementCreatorParameters = { [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]: {
  tagName: K
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]): void
} }[keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]
```

The general approach is to make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with all its keys, to get a union of the properties of the mapped type.  This can be called a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If you have a set of keys `type KK = K1 | K2 | K3 | ⋯` , then `{[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK]` will evaluate to `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3> | ⋯`.

In our case above, `KK` is `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap` and `F<K>` is

```
{
  tagName: K
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]): void
}
```

So `ElementCreatorParameters` is a big union, which you can see if you hover for quickinfo in your IntelliSense-enabled IDE:

```
/* type ElementCreatorParameters = {
    tagName: "object";
    children?: ElementCreatorParameters[] | undefined;
    onCreate?(element: HTMLObjectElement): void;
} | {
    tagName: "a";
    children?: ElementCreatorParameters[] | undefined;
    onCreate?(element: HTMLAnchorElement): void;
} | ... 108 more ... | {
    ...;
} */
```

---

Let's test it out:

```
const e: ElementCreatorParameters = {
  tagName: 'form',
  onCreate: (element) => {
    element // (parameter) element: HTMLFormElement
  },
  children: [
    {
      tagName: 'input',
      onCreate: (element) => {
        element // (parameter) element: HTMLInputElement
      },
      children: [
        {
          tagName: 'a',
          onCreate: (element) => {
            element // (parameter) element: HTMLAnchorElement
          },
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
}
```

Looks good! All the `onCreate` parameters are inferred contextually from the corresponding member of the `ElementCreatorParameters` union, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAwgJwgQ2Ae0wAUdMdlgJMBnKAXigG8oBtAaSgEsUoBrCEPgBmUABIAVALIAZeElTBxOAOYA5chEk4wAXQBcTAFBQowFeuQG2xqAGMAFpzgATbCgD8BgIKYyIADxyyGhYuATEpBqUNAB8NvgooXgQ7gAUEAjBwAYSMkEKSmoaWmDsOgCUBgBu+JzOhgC+UA0s-IIiubKZBebF2jqGhrYJ1MBQEAb5Idh4hCRkFFS0DIw2ZkWWUADkQoSIWwA08YkzlAbp3Wjl9DFGJiYZ8mhQAPQvUKlgkYuY149ZOSk0gAYnspsAbA0jiYHE5XKgDCwbCZVvd7usLBNttwwABXYCHZH3BJJM4ff4Ka50W6otH3CnPN4fL4LCDRP6XbJiIEASRQeOA4KJJihwrsjhcbkRYpRMvRvU2WxwhLpdJJpyxFyewCpNLlaIZYyZn2+bKoHO1gJkXhQDkIQtVaNFjua0LpAydbp0RwahiAA)

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question: I'm right that it is impossible to do same thing with `interface` because we have to use union operation?

Comment: Correct, you can't make it an interface.